# Gradle sync asking for nonexistent build tool version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> Failed to sync Gradle project
>
> Error: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.1.2

However, Build Tools revision 24.1.2 does not exist. Before this error came up, Gradle was giving an error that it required android-19, even though the build.gradle file clearly specifies android-21. This was fixed by installing android-19.

However, because revision 24.1.2 does not exist for Build Tools, it cannot be worked around by simply installing this version. The build.gradle file specifies version 22.0.1, but it seems to be completely ignored. I also tried changing it from the app properties window but it still failed to compile.

What may be causing this is the fact that some of the code was developed on another computer, and slight differences are causing gradle to require incorrect version numbers.

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: You may have a gradle configuration problem. Can you post your gradle config? Your Android Studio version?

Answer (score 0):

You should just open `Android SDK Manager`. It is the app where you install Android SDK and other helper apps.

When it is refreshed you should see there is `Build Tools version 24.1.2` at the top. You should install that.

I've just checked and `24.1.2` is installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio go to 
**Tool => Android => SDK Manager** and update your build tools.
Check if it is installed ?

[image]

Comment: I have already installed "Android SDK Tools" 24.1.2, but I'm reasonably sure that Android Studio is asking for "Android SDK Build-tools" 24.1.2, which is causing the problem. Is this an incorrect interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a gradle configuration problem. Can you post your gradle config?

At the time of writing, the latest Android SDK Build Tools version is 22.0.1 and the latest Android SDK Tools version is 24.1.2.

This would be an example of a gradle config targeting the latest versions (no need to specify the SDK tools version):

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

...
```

Latest release notes can be found here:

**Android SDK Build Tools**:
https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

**Android SDK Tools**:
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html

I hope this helps!